# Azure App Service Facebook

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I've migrated from Azure Mobile Service to an App Service but I'm having difficulty working out how best to implement extended Facebook auth.

In my old implementation I inherited from FacebookLoginProvider and fetched the token from the claims. I then added the CustomFacebookLoginProvider to my login providers. I then use the token to fetch more information about the user (their date of birth, friends and gender). With this information I created a user object and saved it to my DB.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how best to recreate this in App Service as I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as how to set up Facebook authentication, you can find documentation here (and it sounds like you've already figured out this much):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication/

Now that Facebook authentication is set up, you can refer to the following which shows how to obtain user information:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#user-info

```
// Get the credentials for the logged-in user.
var credentials = 
    await this.User
    .GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>(this.Request);

if (credentials.Provider == "Facebook")
{
    // Create a query string with the Facebook access token.
    var fbRequestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
        + credentials.AccessToken;

    // Create an HttpClient request.
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        // Request the current user info from Facebook.
        using (var resp = await client.GetAsync(fbRequestUrl))
        {
            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Do something here with the Facebook user information.
            var fbInfo = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you must add a *using* statement for **System.Security.Principal** to make the **GetAppServiceIdentityAsync** extension method work.

For more information on which Facebook user properties you can query, see the Facebook documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user. Note that you may need to specify which user properties you want as an additional **fields** query string parameter on your call to the Facebook graph.

Comment: I have a blogpost on this here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2017/06/08/using-easy-auth-to-query-facebook-information-via-graph-api/

Answer (score 0):

The only change I had to make when switching from Mobile Service to Mobile App was to change the end of the callback URL in the developer portal to use /.auth/login/facebook/callback instead of /signin-facebook and it worked exactly the same way as before.

Note that this is for a Windows app with a .NET backend; you didn't specify what you're using so your mileage may vary.

Comment: This approach does work as expected but I've no way of getting the Facebook token in order to query Facebook for more information about the user.

Comment: iOS but the client shouldn't matter as this should be happening on the backend.

Comment: I believe on ours we're using InvokeApiAsync on the MobileServiceClient instance to get the user info, but that's C#. I don't develop for iOS so I don't think I can be of any further help, sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following approach to obtain the Facebook Access Token in the iOS app.

App Services includes the Facebook Access Token in the request header, refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-api-authentication/.

To get to the access token, create a Custom API in the Azure Portal, e.g. facebookUserInfo, with the following code:

```
module.exports = {
"get": function (request, response, next) {
    response.send(200, { facebookAccessToken: request.headers['x-ms-token-facebook-access-token'] });
}};
```

In the iOS app, use the following code to query the custom API:

```
    let client = self.table!.client
    if client.currentUser != nil {
        client.invokeAPI("facebookUserInfo", body: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET", parameters: nil, headers: nil, completion: { (result, response, error) -> Void in
            if let resultDict = result {
                if let facebookAccessToken = resultDict["facebookAccessToken"]! {
                    print(facebookAccessToken)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using the Easy Auth feature of Azure App Services, I dont need to worry about authentication. 
I have a blogpost on this. I have explained on how we can use the FB GraphApi's to query FB data. Here is the link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2017/06/08/using-easy-auth-to-query-facebook-information-via-graph-api/

I have the sample code deployed on Github. Here is the link: https://github.com/kaushalp/Facebook-GraphApi-with-EasyAuth